# Da Vinci Resolve cannot play videos - help please!

Tags: nvidia, video, davinci-resolve

I’m new to Ubuntu and I could use some help figuring out why Da Vinci Resolve cannot handle images, or play video. Whenever I import images or video and add them to the timeline, I get this message:

*The GPU failed to perform image processing because of an error (error code 999)*

The images do not display proper colours, and videos do not play – although the audio does.

I am running Da Vinci Resolve Studio version 18.0.1 (paid version) – so the issue cannot be related to codec support.

My laptop is running:

Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Nvidia GeForce RTX 3050 GPU

AMD Ryzen 9 5900HX

The message seems to point to the graphics card, but I followed the process to update my drivers; from the Command Line I selected:

Using Nvidia Driver Metapackage from Nvidia-driver-515 (recommended)

And when I check what drivers I am using it says:
Driver Version: 515.65.01 CUDA Version 11.7

Da Vinci Studio detects my GPU and CUDA is shown as enabled – so I cannot see any obvious issue with the GPU setup.

So now I am out of ideas as to what the problem is - any help would be much appreciated!

Thank you!